# Kafka consumer messages getting deleted before specified retention period

Tags: apache-kafka

So I created a kafka topic and the messages are getting deleted in just 24 hours.. I need it to stay as long as specified **retention.ms** (28 days).. Here is config:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "partitions": 1,
  "replicas": 3,
  "retention": 2419200000,
  "cleanupPolicies": [
    "delete"
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "compression.type": "producer",
    "min.insync.replicas": "2",
    "message.downconversion.enable": "true",
    "segment.jitter.ms": "0",
    "cleanup.policy": "delete",
    "flush.ms": "9223372036854775800",
    "segment.bytes": "1073741824",
    "retention.ms": "2419200000",
    "flush.messages": "9223372036854775800",
    "message.format.version": "2.8-IV1",
    "max.compaction.lag.ms": "9223372036854775800",
    "file.delete.delay.ms": "60000",
    "max.message.bytes": "2000000",
    "min.compaction.lag.ms": "0",
    "message.timestamp.type": "CreateTime",
    "preallocate": "false",
    "index.interval.bytes": "4096",
    "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio": "0.5",
    "unclean.leader.election.enable": "true",
    "retention.bytes": "-1",
    "delete.retention.ms": "86400000",
    "segment.ms": "604800000",
    "message.timestamp.difference.max.ms": "9223372036854775800",
    "segment.index.bytes": "10485760"
  }
}
```

Comment: Kafka doesn't use JSON to configure topics. Please clarify how you use this file

Comment: Have you used any tool to increase the retention period? or using kafka-configs.sh?

Answer (score 0):

This is 24 hours

```
"delete.retention.ms": "86400000",
```